# Getting error regarding repository in liferay

Tags: liferay, liferay-6, cmis

I am facing problem while uploading file in cmis store.
Following code is to upload file.

> fileEntry = DLAppServiceUtil.addFileEntry( 11409,
>   folder.getFolderId(), sourceFileName, contentType, "",
>   sourceFileName+" upload", "", file, serviceContext);

I got following error in console

```
com.liferay.portal.kernel.repository.RepositoryException: There is no valid repository class with class name id 10806
at com.liferay.portal.service.impl.RepositoryLocalServiceImpl.createRepositoryImpl(RepositoryLocalServiceImpl.java:443)
at com.liferay.portal.service.impl.RepositoryLocalServiceImpl.getRepositoryImpl(RepositoryLocalServiceImpl.java:330)
at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor298.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:622)
at com.liferay.portal.spring.aop.ServiceBeanMethodInvocation.proceed(ServiceBeanMethodInvocation.java:115)
at com.liferay.portal.spring.transaction.DefaultTransactionExecutor.execute(DefaultTransactionExecutor.java:62)
at com.liferay.portal.spring.transaction.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:51)
at com.liferay.portal.spring.aop.ServiceBeanMethodInvocation.proceed(ServiceBeanMethodInvocation.java:111)
at com.liferay.portal.spring.aop.ServiceBeanAopProxy.invoke(ServiceBeanAopProxy.java:175)
at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy78.getRepositoryImpl(Unknown Source)
at com.liferay.portal.service.impl.RepositoryServiceImpl.getRepositoryImpl(RepositoryServiceImpl.java:131)
at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor297.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:622)
at com.liferay.portal.spring.aop.ServiceBeanMethodInvocation.proceed(ServiceBeanMethodInvocation.java:115)
at com.liferay.portal.spring.transaction.DefaultTransactionExecutor.execute(DefaultTransactionExecutor.java:62)
at com.liferay.portal.spring.transaction.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:51)
at com.liferay.portal.spring.aop.ServiceBeanMethodInvocation.proceed(ServiceBeanMethodInvocation.java:111)
at com.liferay.portal.spring.aop.ChainableMethodAdvice.invoke(ChainableMethodAdvice.java:56)
at com.liferay.portal.spring.aop.ServiceBeanMethodInvocation.proceed(ServiceBeanMethodInvocation.java:111)
at com.liferay.portal.spring.aop.ChainableMethodAdvice.invoke(ChainableMethodAdvice.java:56)
at com.liferay.portal.spring.aop.ServiceBeanMethodInvocation.proceed(ServiceBeanMethodInvocation.java:111)
at com.liferay.portal.spring.aop.ServiceBeanAopProxy.invoke(ServiceBeanAopProxy.java:175)
at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy79.getRepositoryImpl(Unknown Source)
at com.liferay.portlet.documentlibrary.service.impl.DLAppServiceImpl.getRepository(DLAppServiceImpl.java:3444)
at com.liferay.portlet.documentlibrary.service.impl.DLAppServiceImpl.addFileEntry(DLAppServiceImpl.java:213)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:622)
at com.liferay.portal.spring.aop.ServiceBeanMethodInvocation.proceed(ServiceBeanMethodInvocation.java:115)
at com.liferay.portal.spring.transaction.DefaultTransactionExecutor.execute(DefaultTransactionExecutor.java:62)
at com.liferay.portal.spring.transaction.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:51)
at com.liferay.portal.spring.aop.ServiceBeanMethodInvocation.proceed(ServiceBeanMethodInvocation.java:111)
at com.liferay.portal.spring.aop.ChainableMethodAdvice.invoke(ChainableMethodAdvice.java:56)
at com.liferay.portal.spring.aop.ServiceBeanMethodInvocation.proceed(ServiceBeanMethodInvocation.java:111)
at com.liferay.portal.spring.aop.ChainableMethodAdvice.invoke(ChainableMethodAdvice.java:56)
at com.liferay.portal.spring.aop.ServiceBeanMethodInvocation.proceed(ServiceBeanMethodInvocation.java:111)
at com.liferay.portal.spring.aop.ServiceBeanAopProxy.invoke(ServiceBeanAopProxy.java:175)
at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy193.addFileEntry(Unknown Source)
at com.liferay.portlet.documentlibrary.service.DLAppServiceUtil.addFileEntry(DLAppServiceUtil.java:149)
at com.test.NewPortlet.add(NewPortlet.java:325)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:622)
at com.liferay.portal.kernel.portlet.LiferayPortlet.callActionMethod(LiferayPortlet.java:148)
at com.liferay.util.bridges.mvc.MVCPortlet.callActionMethod(MVCPortlet.java:247)
at com.liferay.portal.kernel.portlet.LiferayPortlet.processAction(LiferayPortlet.java:78)
at com.liferay.util.bridges.mvc.MVCPortlet.processAction(MVCPortlet.java:210)
at com.liferay.portlet.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.java:71)
at com.liferay.portal.kernel.portlet.PortletFilterUtil.doFilter(PortletFilterUtil.java:48)
at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.PortletServlet.service(PortletServlet.java:112)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:728)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:305)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.doFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:116)
at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilter.doFilter(InvokerFilter.java:96)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.invoke(ApplicationDispatcher.java:749)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.doInclude(ApplicationDispatcher.java:605)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.include(ApplicationDispatcher.java:544)
at com.liferay.portlet.InvokerPortletImpl.invoke(InvokerPortletImpl.java:604)
at com.liferay.portlet.InvokerPortletImpl.invokeAction(InvokerPortletImpl.java:649)
at com.liferay.portlet.InvokerPortletImpl.processAction(InvokerPortletImpl.java:312)
at com.liferay.portlet.PortletContainerImpl._doProcessAction(PortletContainerImpl.java:402)
at com.liferay.portlet.PortletContainerImpl.processAction(PortletContainerImpl.java:110)
at com.liferay.portlet.SecurityPortletContainerWrapper.processAction(SecurityPortletContainerWrapper.java:109)
at com.liferay.portlet.RestrictPortletContainerWrapper.processAction(RestrictPortletContainerWrapper.java:75)
at com.liferay.portal.kernel.portlet.PortletContainerUtil.processAction(PortletContainerUtil.java:115)
at com.liferay.portal.action.LayoutAction.processLayout(LayoutAction.java:356)
at com.liferay.portal.action.LayoutAction.doExecute(LayoutAction.java:178)
at com.liferay.portal.action.LayoutAction.execute(LayoutAction.java:79)
at org.apache.struts.action.RequestProcessor.processActionPerform(RequestProcessor.java:431)
at org.apache.struts.action.RequestProcessor.process(RequestProcessor.java:236)
at com.liferay.portal.struts.PortalRequestProcessor.process(PortalRequestProcessor.java:173)
at org.apache.struts.action.ActionServlet.process(ActionServlet.java:1196)
at org.apache.struts.action.ActionServlet.doPost(ActionServlet.java:432)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:647)
at com.liferay.portal.servlet.MainServlet.callParentService(MainServlet.java:546)
at com.liferay.portal.servlet.MainServlet.service(MainServlet.java:523)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:728)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:305)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.doFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:116)
at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.BaseFilter.processFilter(BaseFilter.java:169)
at com.liferay.portal.servlet.filters.secure.SecureFilter.processFilter(SecureFilter.java:293)
at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.BaseFilter.doFilter(BaseFilter.java:59)
at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.processDoFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:204)
at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.doFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:109)
at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.BaseFilter.processFilter(BaseFilter.java:169)
at com.liferay.portal.servlet.filters.jsoncontenttype.JSONContentTypeFilter.processFilter(JSONContentTypeFilter.java:42)
at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.BaseFilter.doFilter(BaseFilter.java:59)
at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.processDoFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:204)
at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.doFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:109)
at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilter.doFilter(InvokerFilter.java:96)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.invoke(ApplicationDispatcher.java:749)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.processRequest(ApplicationDispatcher.java:487)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.doForward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:412)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.forward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:339)
at com.liferay.portal.servlet.FriendlyURLServlet.service(FriendlyURLServlet.java:160)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:728)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:305)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.doFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:116)
at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.BaseFilter.processFilter(BaseFilter.java:169)
at com.liferay.portal.servlet.filters.strip.StripFilter.processFilter(StripFilter.java:359)
at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.BaseFilter.doFilter(BaseFilter.java:59)
at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.processDoFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:204)
at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.doFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:109)
at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.BaseFilter.processFilter(BaseFilter.java:169)
at com.liferay.portal.servlet.filters.gzip.GZipFilter.processFilter(GZipFilter.java:123)
at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.BaseFilter.doFilter(BaseFilter.java:59)
at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.processDoFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:204)
at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.doFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:109)
at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.BaseFilter.processFilter(BaseFilter.java:169)
at com.liferay.portal.servlet.filters.secure.SecureFilter.processFilter(SecureFilter.java:293)
at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.BaseFilter.doFilter(BaseFilter.java:59)
at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.processDoFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:204)
at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.doFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:109)
at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.BaseFilter.processFilter(BaseFilter.java:169)
at com.liferay.portal.servlet.filters.i18n.I18nFilter.processFilter(I18nFilter.java:243)
at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.BaseFilter.doFilter(BaseFilter.java:59)
at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.processDoFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:204)
at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.doFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:109)
at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.BaseFilter.processFilter(BaseFilter.java:169)
at com.liferay.portal.servlet.filters.etag.ETagFilter.processFilter(ETagFilter.java:70)
at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.BaseFilter.doFilter(BaseFilter.java:59)
at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.processDoFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:204)
at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.doFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:109)
at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.BaseFilter.processFilter(BaseFilter.java:169)
at com.liferay.portal.servlet.filters.jsoncontenttype.JSONContentTypeFilter.processFilter(JSONContentTypeFilter.java:42)
at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.BaseFilter.doFilter(BaseFilter.java:59)
at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.processDoFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:204)
at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.doFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:109)
at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.BaseFilter.processFilter(BaseFilter.java:169)
at com.liferay.portal.servlet.filters.autologin.AutoLoginFilter.processFilter(AutoLoginFilter.java:263)
at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.BaseFilter.doFilter(BaseFilter.java:59)
at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.processDoFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:204)
at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.doFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:109)
at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.BaseFilter.processFilter(BaseFilter.java:169)
at com.liferay.portal.servlet.filters.sso.ntlm.NtlmPostFilter.processFilter(NtlmPostFilter.java:83)
at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.BaseFilter.doFilter(BaseFilter.java:59)
at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.processDoFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:204)
at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.doFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:109)
at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.BaseFilter.processFilter(BaseFilter.java:169)
at com.liferay.portal.sharepoint.SharepointFilter.processFilter(SharepointFilter.java:88)
at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.BaseFilter.doFilter(BaseFilter.java:59)
at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.processDoFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:204)
at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.doFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:109)
at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.BaseFilter.processFilter(BaseFilter.java:169)
at com.liferay.portal.servlet.filters.virtualhost.VirtualHostFilter.processFilter(VirtualHostFilter.java:226)
at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.BaseFilter.doFilter(BaseFilter.java:59)
at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.processDoFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:204)
at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.doFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:109)
at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.processDirectCallFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:185)
at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.doFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:96)
at org.tuckey.web.filters.urlrewrite.UrlRewriteFilter.doFilter(UrlRewriteFilter.java:738)
at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.processDoFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:204)
at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.doFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:109)
at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.processDirectCallFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:165)
at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.doFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:96)
at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.processDirectCallFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:165)
at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:502)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:171)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:99)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:953)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:408)
at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1023)
at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:589)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:310)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1146)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:701)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.liferay.portal.repository.cmis.CMISAtomPubRepository
at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1714)
at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1559)
at com.liferay.portal.kernel.util.InstanceFactory.newInstance(InstanceFactory.java:52)
at com.liferay.portal.kernel.util.InstanceFactory.newInstance(InstanceFactory.java:27)
at com.liferay.portal.kernel.util.InstanceFactory.newInstance(InstanceFactory.java:68)
at com.liferay.portal.repository.util.RepositoryFactoryImpl.getInstance(RepositoryFactoryImpl.java:39)
at com.liferay.portal.repository.util.RepositoryFactoryUtil.getInstance(RepositoryFactoryUtil.java:38)
at com.liferay.portal.service.impl.RepositoryLocalServiceImpl.createRepositoryImpl(RepositoryLocalServiceImpl.java:439)
... 186 more
```

I checked many times my repository is correct.

Answer (score 0):

Check which one of the values you pass into that function is 10806. The message "There is no valid repository class with class name id 10806" hints that this is meant to be a class id. If you pass a folder id (for example) this is obviously the wrong parameter for the purpose.

Update, after Daniele's comment: Which version are you using? I've checked the API docs, and it looks like my above answer won't help you too much, but Daniele's pointer to the (fixed) issue might if you run an affected version.

Comment: Often in Liferay 6.2 I've seen this error, specially doing LAR import. Similar issue: https://issues.liferay.com/browse/LPS-31834

Comment: Thanks for the reply.. I got reason why this is happened. But I didn't get solution.
My alfresco repository is exists in liferay. When I open that repository from content->Document and Media->Alfresco Repository once
And then I run my portlet then it will successfully upload my file in that repository. If I didn't open my repository then it gives me error 
com.liferay.portal.kernel.repository.RepositoryException: There is no valid repository class with class name id 10806
I think When i start server at that time repository didn't get refresh.. How can I solve this?

Comment: I am using alfresco 4.2 and liferay 6.2